# VB.Net - Can I check if a string IsNumeric, and if it is convert it to a number to be compared with, all within one IF statements condition?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, logic, conditional-statements

I have a database with a column labeled PrintOnPage. It can hold the values "ALL", "LAST", or a specific page number (1,2,3, etc), they are all stored as a string.

In my code I have the following IF statement:

```
If ((PrintOnPage.ToUpper = "ALL") OrElse
    (PrintOnPage.ToUpper = "LAST" And iPageNo = (_indexDatabase.GetField("LastPage").Trim) OrElse
    (IsNumeric(PrintOnPage) And CInt(PrintOnPage) = iPageNo)) Then
```

The last condition of the IF statement breaks if PrintOnPage is a string that cannot be converted to an INT. Because PrintOnPage can be LAST and iPageNo != to the last page specified in the database until the loop it is in iterated to the proper page, this is an issue.

Even if IsNumeric is False the second part of the condition after the AND is still checked, and thus breaks. I am trying to avoid nesting to many IF statements if I can.

Is there anyway to solve this issue within the same IF statement?

Comment: Did you try AndAlso?

Comment: @HardCode No I did not. I did not know that was a thing until you brought it to my attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AndAlso` in order to short-circuit your `If` evaluation, just like you're using the `OrElse`:

```
If ((PrintOnPage.ToUpper = "ALL") OrElse
    (PrintOnPage.ToUpper = "LAST" AndAlso iPageNo = (_indexDatabase.GetField("LastPage").Trim) OrElse
    (IsNumeric(PrintOnPage) AndAlso CInt(PrintOnPage) = iPageNo)) Then
```

This way, if the first part `IsNumeric(PrintOnPage)` fails, it won't try to evaluate the following part(s).

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm that it is working as described. 
I had though a normal And would short-circuit the condition which is why I did not look further into other AND operators.